# Send array of bytes through ajax using input file

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I'm trying to send an array of bytes from file via AJAX. It's always a PDF fie.

So my Javascript+JQuery is as follows:

```
  function upload() {
    var file = document.getElementById("inputFile").files[0];

    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () {
        var binaryString = this.result;

        var objUploader = {
            element: {
                Name: "example",
                Document: binaryString
            }
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/Uploader/ServiceUploader.svc/saveDocument",
            data: JSON.stringify(objUploader),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=uft-8",
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            }
        });

    };

    //reading file
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

In my WCF service I'm expecting to get an object with this properties:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class UploaderElement
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public byte[] Document { get; set; }
    }
```

And my function definition looks like this.

```
long saveDocument(UploaderElement element);
```

The problem is that binaryString (which is the result of FileReader in JS) is always empty, so in my WCF I'm getting an empty array of bytes in my property "Document".

This is how objUploader looks like when is sent to the service:

```
{"element":{"Name":"example","Document":{}}}
```

How can I fix this. Is there a better way to send PDF bytes representation  to my WCF?. Thank you, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

The `binaryString` will not be empty, but its serialization to JSON will only produce a `{}`. Therefore simply send the file data as octet stream

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/Uploader/ServiceUploader.svc/saveDocument",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/octet-stream",
    data: binaryString,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) { ... }
    error: function (xhr, status, error) { ... }
});
```

and on the server expect only the byte array.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I'm getting `413 Request Entity Too Large`. Even if I have this in my web.config:   `<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsWithMTOM" closeTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:25:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/> `

Comment: @Fentos not an expert in these configurations, but couldn't you try a different binding, e.g a `webHttpBinding`